# What is the meaning of 'latent potential'?

Tags: adjectives

I found a book saying *This book is dedicated to Steve Jobs who challenged me to "think different"and helped me unlock my own **latent potential***. I thought latent and potential are synonyms so I don't get why two words are used in a row. Can you help me understand?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: Not only thinks different - writes different too.

Comment: I gave you a +1, as I thought it was not well-defined in General Reference. That said, you should include your research in the question. Then you will get more +s, and some real answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first stab at the (adjectival) meanings, which you reasonably outline, might suggest that they are the same, that they are synonymous, describing something that will be revealed once certain conditions are satisfied.

For example, we have:

> potential = possible when the necessary conditions exist:
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/potential)

and

> latent = present but needing particular conditions to become active, obvious, or completely developed
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/latent)

There is a hint of difference in the words *possible* and *present*. However, Merriam Webster states things more forcefully:

> Potential = existing in possibility : capable of development into actuality
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latent)

> latent = present and capable of emerging or developing but not now visible, obvious, active,
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latent)

*Latent* therefore describes a real thing that is hidden but may be revealed by some change in circumstance. *Potential* only describes a possibility, perhaps to be revealed by a change in circumstances.

I devise two sentence that have the potential to help. "*Beyond the frontier, the attack was latent, with the massed infantry merely awaiting the word to advance.*" and "*Beyond the frontier, there was political potential for an attack, although no troops had yet left their barracks and negotiations were still in progress.*"

Comment: Thank you @Anton I understand exactly the difference between two words due to your kind and clear explanation.